# How to solve this warning

Tags: reactjs

Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render

Comment: Hi abid , when you want to ask a question in stack-overflow you should add more information about your question like in this example you can add your uesEffect code over here that helps other developers to give you correct answer

Answer (score 0):

Just add an empty dependency array inside `useEffect`'s second argument, like this :

```js
const [state,setState] = useState();

useEffect(()=>{
   ... other tasks or/and update state 
},[]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
useEffect(() => {
    let isMounted = true
    isMounted && "Do Your Thing Here"
    return () => { isMounted = false }
}, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the first `useEffect` (the one that calls `function`, you want) should have an `empty` dependency array. Without it the effect is continually running since `function` changes `state` every time it runs.